# Where should an error in a help center page be reported?

Tags: support, help-center, bug-reporting-process

I didn't find information about where (if at all) an error in the content of a help center page is to be reported. If by chance the place should be here at Meta, this should be stated somewhere.

Comment: I think you're right that it doesn't state in help where to do this. I didn't check meta posts about it though. I'm pretty sure that it depends. Some pages are editable by moderators on the site. Other pages are not and an edit to those goes to all sites.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, all bugs (except security issues or vulnerabilities) should be reported on meta. Which meta? If the bug only affects Stack Overflow, then meta.stackoverflow.com. If it affects all sites, then meta.stackexchange.com.

Comment: *All* bug reports for Stack Overflow go on Meta Stack Overflow. That includes all aspects of the site, including the Help Center. This is stated elsewhere, but not specifically in the Help Center. I don't see why every single feature needs to repeat this statement.

Comment: So, you don't see why every single feature needs to repeat this statement. I think it needs to because a user looking for this information should not be required to search _every single feature_ in order to eventually find it _elsewhere_ (wherever that may be).

Comment: In your opinion, then, every page needs some sort of text on it indicating where to go to file bugs? You obviously were able to find this Meta site, so it does not appear to have been inaccessible or obscure.

Comment: Quoth the Help Center: "If you are unable to find the answer you need here, you can also search for or ask a question about Stack Overflow on Meta!"

Comment: @Cody Gray - Every page already has a footer with a lot of links; in my opinion, one more link for e. g. "Feedback" won't hurt. - Then, you miss the point when you say: _You obviously were able to find this Meta site, so it does not appear to have been inaccessible or obscure._ The question is not how to find Meta, neither how to ask something here. The point is that it should not be necessary for a user to ask where an error is to be reported.

Comment: @John Montgomery - Thanks for the comment, but see above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [help-center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/help-center/info) tag wiki has that info:

> Questions about the help center, bugs with the help center and feature requests regarding the help center and its pages should have this tag.

So it is already stated somewhere.

Leaves the question if that is easily discoverable...

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question where to post. And for the question you mention at the end, I have an answer in mind, which is not "yes". ;-)