# Guiding questions for software recommendations to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Tags: feature-request, help-center

From my own experience (and posts others have made), it seems that Stack Overflow is often confused for a place to ask for recommendations for software tools.

I would like to propose that a link to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ is added to the following section on the "[What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" page:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software
> library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack
> Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.
> Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve
> it.

One possible way this could be done (addition in bold):

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software
> library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack
> Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.
> Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve
> it. **[Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) may be a suitable alternative for questions for software recommendations**

This follows similar wording used on point 5 on the same page.

Per [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/404460/3158933) on another question, this seems to be the appropriate way to suggest this improvement. Is there anything else that I should do try and get this suggestion reviewed?

Comment: I have to see the first question on SO that gets closed as a recommendation question that woud be suitable for Software Recommendations. Asking a good recommendation question is hard. Maybe even harder then asking a question on SO. Directing clueless users to another SE site is not doing the receiving end a big favor.

Comment: Have you seen [Please reword the Ask Question Wizard's intro for Software Recommendations](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385509/1595451)?

Comment: The answers so far seem to imply that the other 10 sites on the linked page are fine with receiving garbage from Stack Overflow. I see a lot more software recommendation questions than I see TeX questions, and yet that site is listed as one site to keep in mind, for example. As far as sites which welcome junk are concerned, should not [Ask Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/) be specifically listed then?

Answer (score 15):

Let's not feed other sites our garbage, thanks.

If their question is something that's on-topic on that site, then and *only* then would I want to recommend that site to them.  Otherwise, let's just... *not*.

Answer (score 11):

We shouldn't make changes that affect other sites without their permission.

You're proposing making a change that would affect Software Recommendations. So have you asked Software Recommendations via [a question on its Meta](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/) whether they are OK with that?

In fact given their reluctance in the past to be mentioned as a migration target I'd be very surprised that Software Recommendations would be happy about us making this change. They have always been concerned about Stack Overflow swamping them.